Authentication Failed on Azure file with PHP/REST API
I would like to move away from an external library I'm using (succesfully) to access some files on azure files.
The goal is to have "simple" and under control code. I just need to read some text files, nothing fancy.
I'm trying to fix the below code (circulating on the net) but I'm getting the nasty message:
AuthenticationFailed Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:333b3e7c-401a-0076-2031-b36e2a000000 Time:2024-05-31T08:04:47.3863148Z
The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'sdfoisiWAIPUnjOHSoiOSDPWhdsojfs==' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET x-ms-date:Fri, 31 May 2024 08:04:47 GMT x-ms-file-range:bytes=0- x-ms-version:2019-02-02 /xxxx/file.txt'.
Anyone have experience with this?
I'm using PHP 8.3.7
Many thanks
<?php

$storageAccount = 'xxxxx';
$containerName = 'xxxxxx';
$fileName = 'xxx/xxxx/file.txt';
$account_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$version = "2019-12-12";

$stringtosign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:". $date . "\nx-ms-version:".$version."\n/".$storageAccount."/".$containerName."/".$fileName;
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$storageAccount.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));
echo "\n\n" . $signature;

$header = array (
    "x-ms-date: " . $date,       
    "x-ms-version: " . $version,       
    "Authorization: " . $signature
);


$url = 'https://' . $storageAccount . '.file.core.windows.net/' . $containerName . '/' . $fileName;


$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_exec ( $ch );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n\n" . $result;

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
?>

I tried different combinations of the signature.

If you are trying to read a text file from the Azure blob storage, you should use the blob.core.windows.net in the $url. You are using file.core.windows.net. but it is for File Share.

I added blob.core.windows.net/ to the URI below and was able to read the text file from Azure Blob Storage.
$url = 'https://' . $storageAccount . '.blob.core.windows.net/' . $containerName . '/' . $fileName;

Code :
app.php :
<?php

$storageAccount = '<accountName>';
$containerName = '<container_name>';
$fileName = 'blobfiles/blobfiles/samplekam.txt';
$account_key = '<storage_key>';

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$version = "2019-12-12";

$stringtosign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:". $date . "\nx-ms-version:".$version."\n/".$storageAccount."/".$containerName."/".$fileName;
$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$storageAccount.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));
echo "\n\n" . $signature;

$header = array (
    "x-ms-date: " . $date,       
    "x-ms-version: " . $version,       
    "Authorization: " . $signature
);

$url = 'https://' . $storageAccount . '.blob.core.windows.net/' . $containerName . '/' . $fileName;

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_exec ( $ch );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n\n" . $result;

if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
?>

composer.json :
{
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.3.7",
        "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "^1.5"
    }
}

Output :
I successfully read the text file's blob data, as shown below:

C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxxx>php app.php

SharedKey xxxxxstr:81CHxxxxxxxxx

Hello, welcome to my world!
I love to listen songs.
Bye

Azure Portal :
Below is the data inside my text file in the Azure Blob Storage.


Thank you Dasari!!!! Works! So I'm feeling quite stupid now. Putting blob.core.windows.net instead of file.core.windows.net did the trick. But until now using the deprecated 'Azure Storage Library for PHP' I was accessing using the file...address. Wondering if with the file address a different authenbtications methodology is triggered and the above code does not work anymore. Best regards

@Simius You are trying to read one of the text blob data from a folder inside a container right? Is this what the blob should look like?
